# Formula to calculate if an invoice received date meet the targeted received date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate if an invoice submission date meets the target set.

My criterias are as per below:

goods received between Mon - Sun, the invoice submission date will only start counting from the 8th day onwards. E.g. goods received between 12 - 18 Aug, the invoice preparation only starts counting from 19th Aug, given a 10 working days leadtime, so my due date to submit the invoice is 2nd Sept.

So how to set a formula to shows that when I enter a date in a cell, it shows Yes or NO. e.g. if I enter 29 Aug in the cell, it says YES and if I enter 3rd Sept, it says no.

Please advise.

Comment: If goods received on 16th Aug 2013{12 Aug(Mon) - 18 Aug(Sun)} then also invoice submission date will start counting from 19th Aug. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite certain about your requirements (eg what to show on 2nd Sept) but if the goods received date is in A2 and the date you enter is in C1 (it can't be actually in the cell to show Yes or No without applying VBA), then:

`=IF(WEEKNUM(C$1,2)=WEEKNUM($A2,2)+2,"YES","no")`

may suit. To check transitions, this can be copied across and down with received dates in ColumnA and select dates in Row1.

[image: SO18503449 example]